# Win 7 Explorer qualified path

Tags: windows-7, path

Does anyone know how to make Win 7 Explorer display the fully qualified path rather than (irrelevant) drive letters as the default? i.e. \servername\sharename\foldername\file.name instead of I:\foldername or even more frustrating Computer > Sharename.  It's not 'display drive letters'

Thanks

Comment: That's not it, you have C:\path.  In a network, I'm looking for \\servername\share\

Comment: You could open a command prompt and type "net use" and that will display the network path for each of the network drive. Or you meant to say you want the Mapped Network Drive to show the full path of the mapping?

Answer (score 1):

If you click in the address bar (to the right of the abbreviated path), the complete folder path will show up.

[image]

Another option is to put the entire path in the title bar. This only works in Windows Classic theme and the path is not selectable. Go into Control Panel -> Folder Options -> View tab

Under advanced settings, there will be an option for "Display the full path in the title bar".

[image]